How can I use python to zip a file geodatabase and add it as an item to AGOL?
I have a script that serves to update a hosted feature layer. Due to recent breaks in the append function from the api, I have transitioned to creating a filegeodatabase using geopanads, uploading that geodatabase to AGOL and then using the uploaded geodatabase to perform the append operation. However, it appears that when I use shutil.make_archive to create the compressed fgdb file, something is going wrong.
Here is the code snippet that creates the fgdb, and then archives it -
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(sales_df, 
                             geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(sales_df['longitude'], 
                                        sales_df['latitude']), crs="EPSG:4326")
sales_gdb_path = csv_path + "sales_update.gdb"

gdf.to_file(sales_gdb_path, driver="OpenFileGDB")

shutil.make_archive(f"{csv_path}sales_update.gdb", "zip", sales_gdb_path)

From this, I then use then use the ArcGIS Api for Python to add the item to the desired location like this:
        elif up == 'sales_update.gdb.zip':
            up_props = {"title": update_id + "_" + str(up), "description": str(up), "type": "File Geodatabase"}
            up_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(up))
            item = gis.content.add(up_props, up_path)
            fgdb_id = item.id
            print(f"---Uploaded {up}---")

Once the archived folder is uploaded this way, the File Geodatabase is unuseable in AGOL. If I try to use the append operation with thie file, the job fails with error code 500. If I try to publish this file as a feature layer, it fails with a message: "There was an error". However if i use file explorer to unzip the gdb and then load it into Pro, it works fine. Similarly, if I use file explorer to zip the original uncompressed filegeodatabase, and then upload this to AGOL manually or using the API, the file does not have any issues and works as intended. I am also noticing that the archive made using shutil is smaller (5964 KB vs 6166 KB) than the zip folder made using file explorer.
So I believe this narrows it down to an issue with the compression method during the shutil.make_archive command. Any ideas?

From make_archive help, it seems like the format compression might change, although you're trying to use zip. Maybe verify based on the doc note: format is the archive format: one of “zip” (if the zlib module is available), “tar”, “gztar” (if the zlib module is available), “bztar” (if the bz2 module is available), or “xztar” (if the lzma module is available).

The other thought is a fGDB looks like a directory on disk.  I've seen cases where zipping a "directory" may fail or miss files if another process has a lock on them. Is it possible geopandas has a lock on 1 or more files? You could troubleshoot this by creating your fGDB in one script. Finish it. In a new script make_archive and see if that zip works

Resolved with help from reddit. The issue ended up being with the arguments provided to .make_archive() producing a file structure that AGOL was not recognizing once uploaded. You can see the solution here - https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1de8aao/comment/l8a0j62/?context=3
